# How to remove extra statusstripbar?

Tags: c#, statusstrip

Suddenly an extra statusstripbar appears above the one I have added (Express 2013). The "two's" are identical and when deleting the original the other one disappears also. The second one only shows on Form at runtime and acts as a clone to the first one. Same labels etc.

I have been searching all my code(*.cs, [design], [designer]) for duplicates and extra entries, but nothing unusual shows up.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is this in WPF or winform?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I'm using Winform. In the process of searching for the error I've tried to delete my menu and add a new one. That didn't fix the problem but made it twice at big. I now have 2 menus and 2 statusstrips. Links for screenshoots: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/km6spd0xvwu4wl4/R9oIf-CNEZ, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake. Turns out the InitializeComponent(); by mistake was placed outside the constructor. Thanks for your replies.